# Testing for DLL references in VBA

Tags: vba, reference

*First, apologies for the generic title - if anyone can suggest a better one, I'd be happy to change it, but right now, I have no clue where to start.*

I have a workbook utilizing a DLL to access a data provider (Bloomberg), and the requirements to get it to work correctly are quite tricky. Furthermore, deployment is a nightmare, since users might need to reference the DLL themselves.
Naturally, I first check wether the library is referenced, before testing the library itself.

Here's my code (which is working as intended) :

```
Public Sub TestBloomberg()
Dim ref As Object
Dim fRef As Boolean
fRef = False
For Each ref In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References
    If ref.GUID = "{4AC751C2-BB10-4702-BB05-791D93BB461C}" Then
        If Not ref.IsBroken Then
            fRef = True
        End If
    End If
Next
If fRef Then
    ' In separate Sub to get around User-defined type error
    Call TestBloombergConnection        
ElseIf Not fRef Then
    ' warn user about missing reference
End If
End Sub
```

As you can see, if the reference to the DLL is set, I proceed checking if the library works as intended (this has a lot of external factors at play, such as wether the server-application is running, the user is logged in, etc.) You can think of this as a simple ON-ERROR-GOTO-wrapped call to the dll.

I am forced to move the actual test of the functionality to another sub, as called from the second if-block. If I have no (or a broken) reference to the dll, even though the library will not be called itself, I will get a User-defined Error. If I move the exact same code to another sub, it will work perfectly.

**Finally, my question:** 
What happens when I run my VBA code, why do I get a (i think) runtime error during compile time? How can my code be so dependend on external factors, that it can't even get to the point of failing?

Comment: a runtime error during compile time? that makes no sense

Comment: what line gives you an error? It seems you're trying to use early binding in `TestBloombergConnection` and if references are not working it throws a compile error (not a runtime error). A runtime error would probably be thrown if you have used late binding...

Comment: @vba4all: If the reference is broken, and I try to call it from the same sub, it will not compile. However, if the reference is broken, and I call it from another sub, my code will run, but I will receive an error in the other sub, on the line where I call the missing DLL. That's where I'm confused about rund- and compile time here...

Comment: @docbrown: thanks for the edit, but my question is more about the conceptual internal workings of vba, rather than this specific test, also I'm not looking for a specific solution, and rather an explanation.

Comment: I don't understand your question here.. Can you be more specific or spend a bit more time on explaining the actual issue? Is it possible for you to share code to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What this behavior demonstrates is that VBA compiles separate subroutines separately and at different times.  I had a similar situation when I was trying to resolve references on behalf of the users (solving a versioning problem, which I got to work, but then abandoned as not worth the trouble).

When you are ready to enter a subroutine, it interprets only as much as it needs to, and you could get a compile time error then, even though to you it seems like you are at run time.

The error you are actually getting is probably a 429 Automation error or something similar. You would get that if you have a broken link (dll moved, deleted, or not registered).  What I remember from my project, is that I could reliably handle it if a good reference was saved in the file, or no reference was saved, but if a bad reference was saved, the code had to be isolated similar to what you found.  I think I had mine in a separate class, but the principle is the same.

I think this "interpret only as much as necessary" is considered a feature of VBA.  You can run a certain section of code, even if you have compile errors elsewhere.  This can be useful when you only have a partially written functions or other half-finished stuff, or if you open the file on a computer without some referenced software installed.  It lets at least *some* of the functionality still work.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for... did you find any further documentation about this behaviour? I'm about to deploy this to a client in the financial sector, I'd rather understand whats going on before releasing it into the wild :D

Comment: I don't think they document stuff like this. Did you get it to reliably handle the bad link case when the code was in another routine or module?  If not, I would be seriously tempted to *never* save the reference in the file, always try to add it a run time to minimize the chance of the uncatchable compile exception occurring. Still I do not know if this can be made rock-solid. What if someone saves the file with a reference in then does an upgrade and the .dll changes?  A lot of screwy cases can happen.